# How to configure Hazelcast host port in Spring Boot?

Tags: spring, hazelcast

I'm using hazelcast in my project and want to move hazelcast host:port information into environment variables. Before that I had default configuration that is:

```
<hazelcast-client xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.hazelcast.com/schema/client-config
                               http://www.hazelcast.com/schema/client-config/hazelcast-client-config-3.8.xsd"
                  xmlns="http://www.hazelcast.com/schema/client-config">

    <network>
        <connection-timeout>3000</connection-timeout>
        <connection-attempt-period>1000</connection-attempt-period>
        <connection-attempt-limit>259200</connection-attempt-limit>
    </network>

</hazelcast-client>
```

and I've found that there is possibility to add `<cluster-members>` tag inside `<network>` to provide custom `<address>` for hazelcast instances. I've modified my `hazelcast.xml` file into:

```
<network>
    <cluster-members>
        <address>${HAZELCAST_URL}</address>
    </cluster-members>
    ...
```

But whenever I'm starting my app it shows:

```
2017-11-10 17:55:45 [service,,,] WARN  c.h.c.s.i.ClusterListenerSupport hz.client_0 [dev] [3.8.5] Exception during initial connection to ${HAZELCAST_URL}:5701, exception java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can't resolve address: ${HAZELCAST_URL}:5701
2017-11-10 17:55:45 [service,,,] WARN  c.h.c.s.i.ClusterListenerSupport hz.client_0 [dev] [3.8.5] Exception during initial connection to ${HAZELCAST_URL}:5702, exception java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can't resolve address: ${HAZELCAST_URL}:5702
```

It means it still tries to connect to default port and variable is not resolved. Is there a way to configure it?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass `java.util.Properties` into the client config builder. All you need do is build it from Spring's environment.

```
@Bean
public ClientConfig clientConfig(Environment environment) throws Exception {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        String HAZELCAST_URL = "HAZELCAST_URL";
        properties.put(HAZELCAST_URL, environment.getProperty(HAZELCAST_URL));
        XmlClientConfigBuilder xmlClientConfigBuilder = new XmlClientConfigBuilder("hazelcast-client.xml");
        xmlClientConfigBuilder.setProperties(properties);
        return xmlClientConfigBuilder.build();
}

@Bean
public HazelcastInstance hazelcastInstance(ClientConfig clientConfig) {
        return HazelcastClient.newHazelcastClient(clientConfig);
}
```

Note, there are more elegant ways to do this, the above is just one solution keeping it as simple as possible